# Express.js: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body

Tags: json, express, token

I'm trying to understand what this error means and how to correct it. This is the complete error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&redirects=&prop=info%7Cpageprops&inprop=url&ppprop=disambiguation&titles=COVID-19_pandemic_in_Algeria&origin=* reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

This is the function that causes the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. It is in  getData.js.

A bit of context: I'm retrieving some information from a wikipedia page that I save into a file. Then in another function, I do some processing to the file to get the data I want:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const wiki = require("wikijs").default;

const fetchCurrentData = () => {
  return wiki()
    .page("COVID-19_pandemic_in_Algeria")
    .then((page) => page.content())
    .then((info) => info[1].items[3].content)
    .then((info) => writeToFile(info));
};

function writeToFile(info) {
  try {
    var data = info;
    fs.writeFile("utils/text.txt", data, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}

module.exports = fetchCurrentData;
```

Then I'm calling this function from a cron.js file:

```
  const getNewCases = require("./getData"); // this is the function above
  function job() {
  console.log("Running Cron Job " + new Date());
  getNewCases();
}

job();
```

Comment: So `fetchCurrentData()` returns a promise that doesn't resolve to any useful value so it's not clear how you could use it in a useful way except for a side effect.  It also appears that when you call `fetchCurrentData()` which I think is what you rename to `getNewCases()` when you import it, you have no `.catch()` handler to catch errors and thus you get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` warning.  To find the actual source of the invalid JSON error, you will have to look back in your promise chain and see which step is causing that.

Comment: In addition, you should be using `fs.promises.writeFile()` in your promise chain since it already returns a promise and fits much better there.  As it is, the last step of your promise chain is NOT waiting for `fs.writeFile()` to finish before resolving since you're using the older callback version and not tracking it's completion at all.

Comment: So, it seems likely that you're trying to process the data from the file before it's been written since you have no code that actually waits for the `fs.writeFile()` to be done.